# Some questions are not visible

Tags: bug, android-app

Some of the questions appear invisible. I can still scroll down through white space and see answers.  I can see the question itself if I switch to *Edit*.

This does not happen to all questions and I was not able to discover any pattern.

For example, it happens with the following SO Meta post:  [Help Improve The Help & Improvement Queue!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue)

I'm using version `1.0.58` of the app on Samsung Galaxy `SCH-I545` with Android version `4.4.2`.

It looks like this:

> [image: screen capture]

**EDIT**

This very question is *invisible* in app as well.  Now I think it could be something with posts that include images.

Comment: @nicael - done.

Comment: @CanadianLuke - While my case has the same manifestation (no body): this post (as an example) has no code blocks.  Could be the same root cause though.